# Use 2d Array with diffrent size of 2-nd row C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Currently i'm tring to do 2d array in c++ that can have diffrent second column size. This is my code:

```
int **testZadanie;
testZadanie = new int*[testy];
...
for (int i = 0; i<testy; i++)
{
    cin >> liczbaLakomczuchow >> liczbaCiastek;
    testZadanie[i] = new int[liczbaLakomczuchow];
    for (int j = 0; j<liczbaLakomczuchow; j++)
    {
        cin >> czasJedzenia;
        //testZadanie[i, j] = czasJedzenia; this not works
        *testZadanie[i, j] = czasJedzenia;
    }
}
```

But when I want to attach values for each column i got exception. So i'm not sure if I can do this what i actually trying do ? ( declaring dynamic column element for each row and attach for each item in row ? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `x[y][z]` instead of `x[y, z]`.

When you write `*x[y, z]`, the compiler interprets it as `x[z][0]` (which is not what you want) because:

- `a, b` is a comma operator, which evaluates both operands and returns the value of the second one.
- `*a` is equivalent to `a[0]`.

---

<sub>This answer generally applies to builtin types only. You can *overload* `,`, `*` and `[]` operators for a class, changing their behaviour completely.</sub>

<sub>If you don't know what *operator overloading* is, just ignore this remark.</sub>